# SQL - Generate column from sum of columns from different table

Tags: sql, sum, mariadb, calculated-columns, create-table

I have two tables: The first one contains numeral values, it looks like this:

[image]

The `id` column is the primary key; it has the attribute `AUTO_INCREMENT`. All columns have the datatype `INT`.

Now my question: Can I create a table like the following:

```
create table testsumtable
(
    id int primary key auto_increment,
    sumColumn int generated always as (sum(SELECT intone, inttwo, intthree FROM valuestable WHERE id=new.id))
);
```

Comment: I'm sorry for the typing mistake: It is intthree with two and not three 'e'.

Comment: Are you just looking to create a generated column that contains the sum of the three other columns?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you just looking to create a generated column that contains the sum of the three other columns?

If so, you should add it directly to the original table:

```
alter table mytable
add column sumColumn as (intone + inttwo + intthree)
```

If you don't want (or can't) alter the original table, I would suggest creating a view instead:

```
create view myview as
select id, intone, inttwo, intthree, intone + inttwo + intthree sumColumn from mytable
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I'll just create a sumColumn as you suggested and make the sumColumn from the sumTable as a foreign key pointing to the sumColumn from the first table.